# Using the concept of vector equation of straight lines, show the following problem:

Tags: geometry, vectors, vector-analysis

Using the concept of vector equation of straight lines, show the following problem:

If P, Q be the mid points of sides AB, CD of a parallelogram ABCD, show that DP and BQ cut diagonal AC at its points of trisection, which are also the points of trisection of DP and BQ respectively.

How to solve it using the concept of vector equation of straight lines, please help.

Comment: I think the proof by this way is very very ugly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg. The only reason the proof in my A is brief is that  I already knew the result  so I knew which values of $x$ and $y$ to plug in. It's  the "rabbit out of the hat" kind of proof, which is rarely pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B=A+V.$ Then $C=D+V .$ And $Q=D+V/2$ is the mid-point of $CD.$

The lines $\{A+x(Q-A):x\in \mathbb R\}$ and $\{D+y(B-D):y\in \mathbb R\}$ intersect where $A+x(Q-A)=D+y(B-D)$.

If $x=2/3$ and $y=1/3$ we have $$A+x(Q-A)=D+y(B-D)\iff$$ $$\iff 3A+3x(Q-A)=3D+3y(B-D)\iff$$ $$\iff 3A+2(Q-A)=3D+(B-D)\iff$$ $$\iff 2(Q-D)=B-A \iff$$ $$\iff 2(V/2)=B-A\iff  V=B-A.$$ When $y=1/3$ the point $D+y(B-D)=(2D+B)/3$  trisects the segment $BD$. And when $x=2/3$ the point $A+x(Q-A)=(A+2Q)/3$ trisects the segment $AQ$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beautiful way to prove by drawing line BQ. But you want to solve it by using the concept of vector.

HINT. Let DP cut AC at X. Then you must prove that $\vec{XA} + \vec{XD} + \vec{XB} = \vec{0}$.

Comment: @hyprfrcb But... they do.

Answer (score 0):

Without less beauty, let be x,y the paralelogram vectors, parametrized as a linear combination growing into the $y$ axes. Then

- $A=0, P=x/2, Q=y+x/2$

he first cross:

- PD=x/2+t(y-x/2),
- AC=t(x+y)

is solved for $t=1/3$, and the second cross:

- BQ=x+t(y+x/2-x),
- AC=t(x+y)

is solved for $t=2/3$, proving the result.

Comment: Why do you use the same parameter $t$ for both $PD$ and $AC$? There’s no particularly good reason to believe that the lines will intersect at the same value of the parameter. If you had instead parameterized $PD$ as $y+t(x/2-y)$, then there’d be no solution to the equation.

Comment: @amd Then how to write the solution

Comment: Of course there is a particular reason to know the lines will intersect. The proof take the freedom of consider a parameter with a convex combination of the points, growing into the diagonal $y$ axis. Sure you can have also a proof with a different selection with two parameters $s$ and $t$. Feel free to write it as a different answer. That is also why the proof ends with the $t$ values only instead to prove back with them the ratio 1:1:1....

Comment: Your answer would be much improved by explaining all of that in the first place.